# Paged List: Declaring the same model differently in an MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I have the below small View for Surveys:

```
@model IEnumerable<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>

@if (ViewBag.canCreate)
{
    <a href="Surveys/Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm createButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create a New Survey</a>
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OwnerOrganization.Name)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn-default btn-sm noDecoration" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OwnerOrganization.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                @{
                    string createdDate = item.CreatedDate.Date.ToString("d");
                }
                @createdDate
            </td>

            @if ((User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (item.OwnerOrganizationId == ViewBag.currentUserGroupId))
            {
                <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn-success btn-sm noDecoration" })
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I'm trying to add the same Paged List functionality I have on a View for Member Projects to the Surveys view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PROJECT.Models.MemberProjects>
@using PagedList.Mvc

....

<div class="paginationWrapper">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, pageSize = ViewBag.pageSize, noSearch = true }))
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">

        @Html.Partial("_Pagination")

    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to implement the same though, my properties are flagged saying they do not contain a definition for the property nor do they have an extension method of the property accepting a first argument of type `PagedList.IPagedList<Project.Models.Surveys>`.

```
@model IEnumerable<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>
@using PagedList.Mvc

@if (ViewBag.canCreate)
{
    <a href="Surveys/Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm createButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create a New Survey</a>
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            /* Error */
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
        </th>
        <th>
            /* Error */
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OwnerOrganization.Name)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            /* Error */
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></th>
    </tr>

    ....

</table>
<div class="paginationWrapper">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page, pageSize = ViewBag.pageSize, noSearch = true }))
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">

        @Html.Partial("_Pagination")

    </div>
</div>
```

Clearly this is because I'm attempting to specify the model in two different ways, but I'm not quite sure how best to get around it. Can anyone offer some advice? I'm still fairly new to MVC development.

Comment: It seems to me that IPagedList ought to implement IEnumerable, thus you should only need to the single `@model PagedList.IPagedList<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>` directive and not the other one.

Comment: If I have both declared or remove the one with `IEnumerable` declaration, everything with `model.*` or `item.*` is flagged. If I remove `PagedList.IPagedList<PROJECT.Models.MemberProjects>`, everything else is fine, but my `Html.PagedListPager()` is then flagged.

Comment: If `PagedList.IPagedList<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>` must implement `IEnumerable<T>` to be able to use it the way you want to here. Does it implement `IEnumerable<T>`? If it does not, are you able to change it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you Jeremy?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic: Have U tried my answer? Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem. For this I advice you to create your `PagedList` in controller only. You are going to show survey list on your view. So instead of `IEnumerable<PROJECT.Models.Surveys>` create your model for view in controller such a way that it supports `PagedList`. So I am just going to show you how to make a model for `PagedList` in controller. Now suppose you have model like:

```
public class Survey()
{
  public string Subject{get;set;}
  public Organization org{get;set;}
  public DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
}
```

Now you are making `IEnumerable` list of this model. So instead of `IEnumerable` list do the following in your controller. Make another model, suppose `SurveyPagedListModel` like this:

```
public class SurveyPagedListModel()
{
   public IPagedList<Survey> pagedListSurvey{get;set;}  
}
```

Now on your view just do this:

```
 @model SurveyPagedListModel

// Your view code goes here 

 ..................

// Place this code as per your settings where you want to set pagination

 <div class="page_numbers page_numbers-sec">
      <div class="pagination">

      @(Model.pagedListSurvey.PageCount < Model.pagedListSurvey.PageNumber ? 0 :         Model.pagedListSurvey.PageNumber)
      @(Model.pagedListSurvey.PageCount)
      @Html.PagedListPager(Model.pagedListSurvey, page => Url.Action("Index")

      </div>
 </div>
```

css

```
.page_numbers 
{
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
}

.page_numbers-sec{
    color: #333333; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

pagination is the Bootstrap css. Just add bootstrap to your project.